# getElementById return empty values so post empty values

Tags: javascript, dom, axios

I'm working with DOM and web API to POST some information about the company like name, worker's name.

But when I write something in the input DOM can't reach the value and return empty so I post an empty object.

That looks like :

1. adress: ""
2. companyName: ""
3. contactName: ""
4. contactTitle: ""

My form block:

```
<form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="">Company Name</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="companyName"
            placeholder="Company Name!"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="">Contact Name</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="contactName"
            placeholder="Contact Name!"
            value=""
          />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="">Contact Title</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="contactTitle"
            placeholder="Contact Title!"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="">Country</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="inputCountry"
            placeholder="Country!"
          />
        </div>
      </form>
```

And my JS code:

```
'use strict';

let inputCompanyName = document.getElementById('companyName');
let inputContactName = document.getElementById('contactName');
let inputContactTitle = document.getElementById('contactTitle');
let country = document.getElementById('inputCountry');

const btnSubmit = document.getElementById('submit');

let newCompany = {
  companyName: inputCompanyName.value,
  contactName: inputContactName.value,
  contactTitle: inputContactTitle.value,
  adress: country.value,
};

btnSubmit.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  axios
    .post('https://northwind.vercel.app/api/suppliers', newCompany)
    .then(res => {
      console.log('Response', res.data);
      alert('Success!');
    });
});
```

I tried innerHTML and innerText and form method but I cant solve this problem.

Comment: because that object is written when it is evaluated. Those values are not live updating.

Answer (score 3):

You're reading the values *immediately* upon loading the page, long before the user has had a chance to *enter* any values.

Instead, read the values in the click event:

```
btnSubmit.addEventListener('click', e => {
  let newCompany = {
    companyName: inputCompanyName.value,
    contactName: inputContactName.value,
    contactTitle: inputContactTitle.value,
    adress: country.value,
  };
  // the rest of the click handler logic...
});
```

Comment: Oh I see, but when I use onclick in HTML it's works, I thought I could use it like it.

Comment: @JarlX: *"but when I use onclick in HTML it's works"* - This suggests that you're making other changes than just how you assign the handler function.  Because there is **no way** that "using onclick" will make your code go back in time and update the values that were already used.  In any event, it's best to avoid directly using `onclick` in your markup anyway.  The code shown in the question is a more modern and maintainable way to add an event listener to an element.